# Prove the estimate $\binom{n}{k} \le (\frac{en}{k})^k$

Tags: combinations, binomial-coefficients

Prove the estimate $$\binom{n}{k} \le \left(\frac{en}{k}\right)^k$$ directly from $$e\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n \le n! \le en\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n.$$

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: I transformed into $\binom{n}{k} = \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$ and applied the inequality but it did not go well

Comment: assumes $k\ne0$

Answer (score 3):

Use the other form of the binomial, after cancelling out $(n-k)!$
$$
\binom nk=\frac{n(n-1)\cdots(n-k+1)}{k!}\le \frac{n^k}{e(\frac{k}e)^k}=\frac1e\cdot\left(\frac{en}k\right)^k
$$

Comment: How did you find the inequality with $\frac{n^k}{e(k/e)^k}$? I understand that $n(n-1) \cdots (n-k+1) < n^k$ but not sure about the rest.

Comment: because $n(n-1)\cdots(n-k+1)\le n^k$

Comment: Use $(n-j)\le n$ and the given lower bound of the factorial.

Comment: Yes, but how can you compare $k!$ and $e(k/e)^k$?

Comment: substitute $k$ for $n$ in OP

Answer (score 0):

Using Sterling's approximation(and that the quantities are asymptotic)

$\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!} < \frac{n(n-1)...(n-k+1)}{\sqrt{2πk}*(k/e)^k}< (e/k)^k*(n*n*n*...*n) = (\frac{ne}{k})^k$